# How to hide url path but still GET from redirect PHP

Tags: php

Instagram returns URL like this : `http://example.com/instagram/?code=something`

I do not want to display `?code=something` in address bar but I still want to get value of `code=`

How can I do it in PHP?

Currently, I use like this

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])){

}
```

Thank for your support.

Comment: set to session value, and then change url by header('Locatio...

Comment: Can you post to your answer? please

Comment: Use the post method if you are using  a form

Comment: Can you tell me in your answer. I am not good at this.

Comment: use POST instead of GET

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested only an idea:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
$_SESSION['code']=$_GET['code'];
header('Location:http://example.com/instagram/');
}
```

Comment: Hi. It still returns full URL although I used header('Location:http://example.com/instagram/');

Comment: I still obtain value from session but url do not change ? why that?

Comment: try to read doc of php for headder, http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php, try to set other url for redirect